# JSON to PHP Class Conversion

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON in the following format :

```
{
  "intent": "session",
  "urls": {
    "url1": "http://example.com/url1",
    "url2": "http://example.com/url2"
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "username"
  },
  "sessions": [
    {
      "session": {
        "login": "timeIn",
        "logout": "timeOut"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Initially I was creating a stdclass object in PHP and was instantiating on the fly. Later to make code more robust, instead of making stdclass object I wanted to create a session class, and I would instantiate that class from my calling classes. Just like standard OOPS. However, I was not able to find a way to say add "urls" in the class object. Here I do not want to make another class URL which have vars like url1, url2 and then use it.

Can someone suggest how can I create a class corresponding the JSON object as well as if some JSON to PHP stdclass mapping reference, since the one I found did not worked for me and had incomplete information.

Here is what I have been trying...

```
class session {
    var $intent ;
    var $urls = array($url1, $url);  //Fails
    var $urls->url1;
    var $urls->url2;   //Fail
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Call the constructor like:

`$session = new Session($intent, $urls);`

Put the urls in an array before that call. Or you can put them in one by one with

`$session->setUrl($url1);`

```
class Session {
    var $intent;
    var $urls = array();

    function __construct($intent = "", $urls = "") {
        $this->intent = $intent;
        $this->urls = $urls;
    }

    function setUrls($url) {
        $this->urls[] = $url;
    }

    function getUrls() {
       return $this->urls;
    }
}
```

On a side note, class name should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create the object from the json or the other way round?

Maybe type casting can help you?
Convert json to object

```
        $obj = json_decode('{
                          "intent": "session",
                          "urls": {
                            "url1": "http://example.com/url1",
                            "url2": "http://example.com/url2"
                          },
                          "user": {
                            "name": "username"
                          },
                          "sessions": [
                            {
                              "session": {
                                "login": "timeIn",
                                "logout": "timeOut"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }');
```

change urls from object to array
    $obj->urls = (array)$obj->urls;

so the final object is this

```
    stdClass Object
(
        [intent] => session
        [urls] => Array
        (
                [url1] => http://example.com/url1
                [url2] => http://example.com/url2
        )

        [user] => stdClass Object
        (
                [name] => username
        )

        [sessions] => Array
        (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                        [session] => stdClass Object
                        (
                                [login] => timeIn
                                [logout] => timeOut
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

so you can simply handle an array